# Hide Submit button after send form with load method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I create a form and send request to other page with :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#send").click(function() {
    var text = $("#text").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    $("#exp").load("sendmail.php",{text:text,email:email});
    });

});
```

and my form code :

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="name" id="text" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></li>
    <button class="button" id="send" >send email</button>
    <div id="exp" style="color:green;"></div>
</ul>
```

how i can hide submit button after send mail ?

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send").click(function() {
        var text = $("#text").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        $.post("sendmail.php",{text:text,email:email}, function(){
             $('.form').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

**Html:**

```
<ul class="form">
    <li><input type="text" name="name" id="text" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></li>
    <button class="button" id="send" >send email</button>
    <div id="exp" style="color:green;"></div>
</ul>
```